# How to use GLEW with Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, mingw, glew

I want to use GLEW with Qt under Windows (7 if that matters).

What I did was go to the GLEW website, download the package for windows, then put the glew.dll in System32 folder. In my pro file, I referenced the .lib files with `LIBS += .../path_to_the_libs/glew32.lib` and the same for `glew32s.lib` (not sure what the latter's for). In my QGLWidget subclass, I made sure that `glew.h` is included before `<QGLWidget>` and therefore before `gl.h` and `glu.h`. In the `main()` function the first thing I do is call `glewInit` and call `glGetError` but my application exits with some weird code, like a very large negative number.

I have a suspicion that there are very may thing I do wrong(I am relatively new to Qt and OpenGL and absolutely new to GLEW), but I also have a suspicion that one of the major errors is that the libs, I suppose, were built with MSVC and therefore cannot be linked against with MinGW... Anyway, can anyone please provide a step-by-step instruction how to install GLEW with Qt and use it? I would much appreciate it. Thank you in advance

***Edit:***
Guys, maybe I am asking for too much, but I would really really like a step-by-step instruction :)

Comment: isn't glew32s.lib static version? You need one lib, not both.

Comment: if compiler really differs, you have to compile GLEW yourself.

Comment: GLEW compiled via MSVC should work on MinGW.

Comment: MinGW has some kind of ability to link with C libs compiled by MSVC (not C++ though). I had some problems with that before, but I can confirm that `glew32s.lib` links and works with just `-lglew32s` on the linker command, no hacks needed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're not supposed to call `glewInit()` before you have your OpenGL context ready. Call it just before your first `gl*` calls, not at the beginning of `main`. That should do the trick.

Also, don't use `glew32.lib` and `glew32s.lib` simultaneously - the former is to use along with the DLL file and the latter is static (your .exe gets bigger but you don't have to distribute your application with the .dll). Decide and use either.

Comment: This helped a lot!  For reimplementers of QGLWidget: The best place to put the call to `glewInit()` is at the top of your `initializeGL()` function.  This _will_ result in `glewInit()` getting called for each GL widget you create, but that doesn't seem to bother anything.

Answer (score 0):

Qt 4.7 can create any OpenGL Context. Use QGLFormat.setProfile() and QGLFormat.setVersion()

The only disadvantage is that you still do not have OpenGL 3+ bindings.

Step by step solution:

1. Make new subclass of QGLWindget.
2. In constructor of new class set up new QGLContext with proper OpenGL numbers.
3. Call glewInit().
4. Pass context to constructor QGLWidnet.

If I remember correctly it should do! GLEW dll should be placed in proper system folders, and compiler options attached, but they are the same as for GLEW without QT.

Comment: how to access Opengl 3 related API calls without GLEW ?

Comment: Now, thats different question!